# What does install4j use to validate an add-on installer can be run on a user's machine?

Tags: java, install4j

My add-on installers I've created have worked successfully; I create a new project, marked as an add-on installer, and set the "For application with ID" field with the application ID of the original app I'm "adding on" to.

But I found one user who it won't work for. We validated that the application was indeed installed and that he was running the executable on the correct machine.

Does anyone know exactly how install4j checks if the add-on installer can be run? (e.g. registry key, a specific file etc so I can find exactly what to compare between a working machine and the particular user)

[image]

Comment: What version of install4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\installations`, it should contain a value `instdir[application ID]`. If not, maybe the installer was run without privileges and the key is in HKCU instead of HKLM.

Comment: I copy+pasted the OPs question into the install4j support form just for grins. The reply was the same as this answer: *"install4j stores this information in the registry. If you don't require admin rights it is store in the key for the current user under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\install4j\installations The installation was perhaps done with a different user account or your customer "cleaned up" his registry.*